# Sync an arbitrary number of datasources to one central database

Tags: database, apache-camel, integration

The databases and their tables are guaranteed to be identical. One database will act as "master" and import data from other databases to itself. Right now I have succeeded in doing this, but I manually construct an insert query in a very archaic way:

1. I execute a query against one database using an endpoint like `sql:file:somefile.sql?dataSource=dataSource1&outputHeader=result`.
2. I iterate the resulting set of data and constuct insert queries for each row and insert into the master database.

```
split(header("result"))
    .to("direct:handleSingleRow")
.end()
```

This is how I do it right now when handling individual rows, where all column names and values are extracted from the result set row by row:

```
String insertQuery = String.format("INSERT INTO %s.%s (%s) VALUES (%s)", schema, tableName, columns, join(", ", parsedRowValues.values()));
```

Which results in something like `INSERT INTO public.table (columnone, columntwo) VALUES (1, 2)`.

I then pass this query to my "master" database like so

```
sql:INSERT INTO public.table (columnone, columntwo) VALUES (1, 2)?dataSource=master
```

Is there a better way to do this using Camel? I do not want to use hibernate and POJOs, beacause I want the end user to be able to drop sql files into a folder and those will then be executed. Is there any way to just take one result set from the request and input it to the next?

Optimally I would like do this:

```
to("sql:file:query.sql?dataSource=dataSource1&outputHeader=result")
.to("sql:?inputHeader=result")
```

What is the cleanest way to copy data from one database to another using Camel? How can I improve on my current solution?

Comment: Which database server is this?

Comment: Sorry, probably should have mentioned this. At the moment i only plan to support postgres > 9.

Comment: Postgres has built in replication. Why would you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because I also do database migration, database snapshots and more. I would like to support more than one db

Comment: Aah so your use case is not satisfied by pgSQL replication. Cleanest way to mass copy data like this would probably be to look at an ETL tool like pentaho which does these type of blind copying jobs well. There is no component that will do this in camel the way your want. You can develop your own component though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but then db native replication or doing the legwork myself is preferable. It works as is and it doesn't cost a dime, I just wanted a cleaner way using Camel.